# Can’t RDP a VM created via attaching an unmanaged windows vhd (PowerShell and ARM Template)

Tags: azure, powershell

From the last few days I am encountering a scenario where I am not able to RDP an Azure VM created via attaching an unmanaged windows vhd.
I explain the steps performed,

1. Created a unmanaged VM image (vhd) from an azure VM [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sa-copy-generalized)

   a.  Created an Azure VM (Windows Server 2016) with unmanaged OS Disk.

   b.  Generalize the VM using Sysprep [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sa-copy-generalized).

   c.  Deallocated the VM and set the state to generalize using PowerShell.

```
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName '[RG]' -Name '[vhdtest]' 

Set-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName '[RG]' -Name '[vhdtest]' –Generalized

Save-AzureRmVMImage -ResourceGroupName '[RG]' -Name '[vhdtest]' `
    -DestinationContainerName 'newvhds' -VHDNamePrefix 'new3'
```

I can see the new VHD got copied at system blob container.

2. Created a VM with the unmanaged disk by attaching VHD created in step 1 Using PowerShell.
   Performed following steps or PowerShell commands to create VM and attach the VHD,

```
# created Subnet
$rgName = "Technovate2020_Logicators-RG"
$subnetName = "mySubNet-attach"
$singleSubnet = New-AzureRMVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/24

# created virtual Network with assignig Subnet
$location = "CentralUS"
$vnetName = "myVnetName-attach"
$vnet = New-AzureRMVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location `
    -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/16 -Subnet $singleSubnet


# created Network Security Group rule to enable RDP
$nsgName = "myNsg-attach"
$rdpRule = New-AzureRMNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name myRdpRule -Description "Allow RDP" `
    -Access Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 110 `
    -SourceAddressPrefix Internet -SourcePortRange * `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 3389


# created Network Security Group and assiging rules
$nsg = New-AzureRMNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location `
    -Name $nsgName -SecurityRules $rdpRule


# created Public IP
$ipName = "myIP-attach"
$pip = New-AzureRMPublicIpAddress -Name $ipName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location `
    -AllocationMethod Dynamic


# created Network Interface Card
$nicName = "myNicName-attach"
$nic = New-AzureRMNetworkInterface -Name $nicName -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
 -Location $location -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id


# created VM Configurations
$vmName = "myVM-attach"
$vmConfig = New-AzureRMVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize "Standard_D4s_v3"
# Assign NIC
$vm = Add-AzureRMVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $nic.Id


# Unmanaged OS Disk to attach (already copied the vhd from 'system' container to 'vhds')
$osDiskUri = "https://technovate2020logicators.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/new3-osDisk.vhd"


# assigning OS Disk using 'attach' option
$osDiskName = $vmName + "osDisk"
$vm = Set-AzureRMVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $osDiskName -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption attach -Windows


#Create the VM
New-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm
```

VM with unmanaged OS Disk created.
Issue/problem: Cannot RDP the VM.

Additional information:-
If I create the same VM with unmanaged OS Disk, but using `fromImage` option instead of `attach` then I am allowed RDP the VM.

Answer (score 0):

The commands you are running to perform this process belong to a depreciated powershell module, AzureRm.  I would recommend you first uninstall the azurerm powershell module and install the new az powershell module (the modules cannot coexist on the same machine), update your script to use the new powershell module cmdlets, and see how that works for you.

Comment: Thank you, Williams for the response and suggestions.

Comment: I tried the following to get the vhd working for my requirements, 
1- Create a VM using Unmanaged OS Disk. (was doing earlier as well.)
2- In order to create a VHD out of it, just delete the VM and other related resources (for example, public IP, nic, nsg, etc)
3- Will left with the vhd of the VM. 
4- Create the VM attaching the vhd from step-3 and it works (tried with ARM template).

Basically no need to perform the steps mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sa-copy-generalized#generalize-the-vm